# JQuery Autocomplete Working in IE8 But Not In Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome

The code below works in IE8 but not in Chrome. When I run it in Chrome, the little "wait" icon appears and then disappears, with nothing else happening. In IE8, the autocomplete runs successfully. Oddly, I'm noticing that [the JQuery Autocomplete Remote datasource example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) is not working in IE8 or Chrome.

```
        $(function () {
            function log(message) {
                $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
                $("#log").scrollTop(0);
            }

            var myString = gatewayUrl + "/rds/reportData/report/" + myReportId;

            $("#conditions").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    debugger;
                    $.get(gatewayUrl + "/rds/outputFormat/report/" + myReportId + "/xml", { p_Condition: request.term }, function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.selectNodes("/dataset/data/row/value"), function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.nodeTypedValue,
                                value: item.nodeTypedValue
                            }
                        }));
                    })
                },
                minLength: 2,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    log(ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.value : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: The problem on the JQUI site is that their search.php appears to be missing. Someone should probably file a bug report.

Comment: I see now that nodeTypedValue only works in Internet Explorer. What would be the equivalent in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, You could stick with using the built in functions.

Have you looked at [jQuery.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) function?